# How to install Parse Server on Amazon EC2?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I don't want to use Elastic Beanstalk. 
I'd like to install Parse Server from scratch into my EC2 instance running in South America, for production purposes. All the tutorials I found was about EB in us-east.

Answer (score 4):

actually it's pretty simple..

You need to do the following:

1. Install nodejs (please refer here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)
2. After nodejs is installed please write the following commends

```html
mkdir parse-server
cd parse-server
npm init
npm install parse-server --save 
./node_module/.bin/parse-server --myAppId hello --masterKey myMasterKey
```

change **myAppId** and **myMasterKey** to something more secure :) and you have parse-serve will run on the default port (1337). From there you can use parse-server docs to add more capabilities like: cloud code, push, email integration and more and more..